# My C# program says one of my files can't be found, the file that is connected to my SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, .net, missing-features

My C# program was running until I moved them around and now, it says I one of the forms can't be found. Attached are the warnings. I have tried everything so I'm afraid I'll have to manually edit the code... for the hundredth time... The missing form IS in the project folder, still it says the form can't be found. This form can't be re written because it's the one that's connected to my sql server.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't say anything about a form, your exe is not compiling and therefore not getting copied to the output folder. You need to fix whatever build error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy the project in other folder
2. Delete the debug folder and try to reload the project
3. if you get any message exclude the the debug folder
4. Rebuild the project

I hope this will work.

Comment: The parent file, 'Form4.cs', for file 'Form4.Designer.cs' cannot be found in the project file. WindowsFormsApplication3

Comment: That's the warning on my whole project why it can't run, i'm guessing

Comment: It means your project is not properly copied either exclude form4.cs from project file or copy project again.

Answer (score 0):

check all the paths and references you set are correct or clear all references and then give reference again. this is absolutely a path issue.
that's it.